# Is there a function in Pandas pivot table to add the difference of multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have the following pandas DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo",
                         "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar",'foo' ],
                   "B": ["one", "one", "one", "two", "two",
                         "one", "one", "two", "two", 'two'],
                   "C": ["small", "large", "large", "small",
                         "small", "large", "small", "small",
                         "large", 'large'],
                   "D": [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,8],
               })
```

with the following output:

```
print(df)

    A   B   C       D
0   foo one small   1
1   foo one large   2
2   foo one large   2
3   foo two small   3
4   foo two small   3
5   bar one large   4
6   bar one small   5
7   bar two small   6
8   bar two large   7
9   foo two large   8
```

then I am doing a pivot table as follows:

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='D', index=['A'],
                    columns=['B','C'])
```

With the following output:

```
print(table)

B   one             two
C   large   small   large   small
A               
bar   4      5       7        6
foo   2      1       8        3
```

How could I add the difference between `large` and `small` (`large` - `small`) for `one` and `two` (`diff` in table below)?
The expected output would be:

```
B   one                 two
C   large   small diff  large   small difff
A               
bar   4        5   -1     7       6    1
foo   2        1    1     8       3    5
```

I saw some previous answers but only treated 1 column. Also, ideally would be done using the `aggfunc`

Additionally, how would be the way to re-transform the table into the initial format?
Expected output would be:

```
  A   B   C     D 
0  foo one small 1 
1  foo one large 2 
2  foo one large 2 
3  foo two small 3 
4  foo two small 3 
5  bar one large 4 
6  bar one small 5 
7  bar two small 6 
8  bar two large 7 
9  foo two large 8 
10 bar one diff -1 
11 bar two diff 1 
12 foo one diff 1 
13 foo two diff 5
```

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
diffs = (table.groupby(level="B", axis="columns")
              .diff(-1).dropna(axis="columns")
              .rename(columns={"large": "diff"}, level="C"))

new = table.join(diffs).loc[:, table.columns.get_level_values("B").unique()]
```

- groupby the level "B" of columns ("one", "two"...)
- take difference from left to right (diff(-1))

  - i.e., compute "large - small" values
- since there's nothing next to small further, it will be all NaNs, drop it
- rename the "large"s which actually now hold the differences
- join with the pivoted table and restore the "one", "two" original order

to get

```py
>>> new

B     one              two
C   large small diff large small diff
A
bar     4     5   -1     7     6    1
foo     2     1    1     8     3    5
```

Comment: Thank you! solved. Might I also ask you a follow-up question, which would be how to re-transform the table into the initial format?
 Expected output would be: 
```    A   B   C       D
0   foo one small   1
1   foo one large   2
2   foo one large   2
3   foo two small   3
4   foo two small   3
5   bar one large   4
6   bar one small   5
7   bar two small   6
8   bar two large   7
9   foo two large   8
10  bar  one diff     -1
11  bar   two diff     1
12 foo    one diff        1
13 foo    two diff        5
```

Comment: @TabernaA glad to be of help. What pivot does is long-to-wide, inversion would be wide-to-long, and `.melt` can help there; so something like `new.melt(ignore_index=False, value_name="D")`? That would longify the result while keeping the index (A) information, and also renaming back the contents (numbers to-be column) to "D".